# Fluent NHibernate only cascade delete of association record

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

We're using NHibernate for our membership system. A `User` can be a member of many `Role`s and a `Role` can have many users.

When a `Role` or a `User` is deleted, it should only cascade the delete of the association record ("RoleUsers" table).

Deleting a `Role` works as expected. However, deleting a `User` does not delete the association record and as such fails due to a foreign key constraint.

My mapping on the `Role` side:

```
        HasManyToMany(r => r.Users)
            .Access.CamelCaseField()
            .Table("RoleUsers")
            .ParentKeyColumn("RoleId")
            .ChildKeyColumn("UserId")
            .AsSet();
```

Mapping on the `User` side:

```
        HasManyToMany(u => u.Roles)
            .Access.CamelCaseField()
            .Table("RoleUsers")
            .ParentKeyColumn("UserId")
            .ChildKeyColumn("RoleId")
            .Inverse(); // we'll add user to role, not role to user
```

And the failing test:

```
    [Test]
    public void Deleting_user_should_not_delete_roles()
    {
        var user = new User("john@doe.com", "John", "Doe", "Secr3t");
        var role = new Role("Admin");
        role.AddUser(user);

        object id;
        using (var txn = Session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            id = Session.Save(user);
            Session.Save(role);
            txn.Commit();
        }

        Session.Clear();

        var fromDb = Session.Get<User>(id);

        using (var txn = Session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            Session.Delete(fromDb);
            txn.Commit();
        }

        Session.Query<Role>().Count().ShouldEqual(1);
    }
```

I've tried every combination of `Cascade` on the user mapping and it either fails or deletes the association record AND the role (not what I want).

Answer (score 2):

**Inverse** and **cascading** are two different concepts. And of course, both **are** supported on `<many-to-many>` relation. See the documentation 6.8 (scroll down almost to 6.9)

http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-bidirectional

1) Firstly, we can remove the **inverse** setting of the `User.Roles` collection. This will straightens the behavior of the *Users`s* relations to *Roles*, and force their deletion before *User* itself is deleted.

2) Secondly. If the *Roles* collection of the *User* is marked as *`inverse`*,

```
HasManyToMany(u => u.Roles)
  ...
  .Inverse(); // we'll add user to role, not role to user
```

deletion of any *User*, will **never** trigger deletion of the pair. That's because we are explicitly saying: *the one and only one who care about the relation is the `Role`*.

So if we would like to continue in your scenario:

> .Inverse(); **// we'll add user to role, not role to user**

we should be consitent. "we'll remove user from roles, not roles from user":

```
[Test]
public void Deleting_user_should_not_delete_roles()
{
  var user = new User("john@doe.com", "John", "Doe", "Secr3t");
  var role = new Role("Admin");
  role.AddUser(user);

  object roleId;
  object id;
  using (var txn = Session.BeginTransaction())
  {
    id = Session.Save(user);
    roleId = Session.Save(role);
    txn.Commit();
  }

  Session.Clear();

  // take both from DB
  var userFromDb = Session.Get<User>(id);
  var roleFromDb = Session.Get<Role>(roleId);

  using (var txn = Session.BeginTransaction())
  {
     // HERE just remove the user from collection
     roleFromDb.Users.Remove(userFromDb);

     // all relations will be deleted
     Session.Save(roleFromDb);
     txn.Commit();
  }
  ... 
  // assertions
  // "John's" relation to Role "admin" is deleted
}
```

*NOTE:*
*3) Cascade was not used in there, but could help to reduce Session.Save(user)...*

#### EDIT: Extending the point 3)

**Deletion of the user** as Ben Foster noticed in a comment.

3) We should even allow the `Role` to manage its *Users* collection completely. Let's introduce the `casdace="all"` *(casdace="all-delete-orhpan" if User without any Role should be deleted at all)*. Now we can add/update users only via Role object.

the mapping of the Role's Users collection should look like:

```
HasManyToMany(r => r.Users)
  .Access.CamelCaseField()
  .Table("RoleUsers")
  .ParentKeyColumn("RoleId")
  .ChildKeyColumn("UserId")
  //.Cascade.All(); // just save or update instance of users
  .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan(); // will even delete User without any Role
  .AsSet();
```

Having inverse and cascade we can adjust the test:

```
[Test]
public void Deleting_user_should_not_delete_roles()
{
  var user = new User("john@doe.com", "John", "Doe", "Secr3t");
  var role = new Role("Admin");
  role.AddUser(user);

  object roleId;
  using (var txn = Session.BeginTransaction())
  {
     // I. no need to save user
     roleId = Session.Save(role);
     ...
```

And later call this to get rid of a User

```
...
using (var txn = Session.BeginTransaction())
{
  var user = Session.Get<User>(id);
  var roles = user.Roles.ToList();
  roles.ForEach(role => role.RemoveUser(user))
  // II. not only relations, but even the User is deleted
  // becuase updated roles triggered delete orhpan
  // (no Session.Update() call there)
  txn.Commit();
}
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't actually answer the question, but it's close. I'm asking how to delete the **User** and the association, not *just* the association. Since the Inverse setting tells NHibernate what side to look for changes, the answer is that we need to remove the user we want to delete from all of its roles before deleting i.e. `user.Roles.ForEach(role => role.RemoveUser(this))`. If you'd like to update your answer I'm happy to mark it as so.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't meet our requirements as it doesn't support removing a role assignment from a user. We should not cascade deletes on the Role. I'm practically answering this myself :)